# Cannot scale down to zero with ASB in Azure Container Apps

Tags: azure, azureservicebus, masstransit, azure-container-apps

I have a .NET 8.0 console application in a container, which is deployed to ACR and run on ContainerApps.
Application is built on MassTransit, uses Azure Service Bus queues.
It works great, but I always have one active replica running even there are no requests at all.

I tried it both ways with having my scaling rules with **queue** and **connection**, no change at all.

Unlike [this issue](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-container-apps/issues/952), I have no key-vault references, my secrets are **Container Apps Secret**s.
Here's the JSON of my resource:

```json
{
    "id": "<redacted>",
    "name": "<redacted>",
    "type": "Microsoft.App/containerApps",
    "location": "West Europe",
    "tags": {
        "created_by": "cdktf",
        "environment": "Staging"
    },
    "systemData": {
        "createdBy": "1a6afc85-d01a-45ad-8de2-4aa26f74828d",
        "createdByType": "Application",
        "createdAt": "2023-12-12T10:39:02.4044595",
        "lastModifiedBy": "1a6afc85-d01a-45ad-8de2-4aa26f74828d",
        "lastModifiedByType": "Application",
        "lastModifiedAt": "2023-12-19T07:47:57.7108815"
    },
    "properties": {
        "provisioningState": "Succeeded",
        "runningStatus": "Running",
        "managedEnvironmentId": "<redacted>",
        "environmentId": "<redacted>",
        "workloadProfileName": null,
        "outboundIpAddresses": [
            "<redacted>"
        ],
        "latestRevisionName": "<redacted>--8psntt0",
        "latestReadyRevisionName": "<redacted>--8psntt0",
        "latestRevisionFqdn": "",
        "customDomainVerificationId": "<redacted>",
        "configuration": {
            "secrets": [
                {
                    "name": "container-registry-admin-password"
                },
                {
                    "name": "servicebus"
                }
            ],
            "activeRevisionsMode": "Single",
            "ingress": null,
            "registries": [
                {
                    "server": "<redacted>",
                    "username": "<redacted>",
                    "passwordSecretRef": "container-registry-admin-password",
                    "identity": ""
                }
            ],
            "dapr": null,
            "maxInactiveRevisions": null,
            "service": null
        },
        "template": {
            "revisionSuffix": "",
            "terminationGracePeriodSeconds": null,
            "containers": [
                {
                    "image": "<redacted>",
                    "name": "processor",
                    "args": [
                        "dotnet",
                        "Processor.dll"
                    ],
                    "env": [
                        {
                            "name": "DOTNET_ENVIRONMENT",
                            "value": "Staging"
                        }
                    ],
                    "resources": {
                        "cpu": 1,
                        "memory": "2Gi",
                        "ephemeralStorage": "4Gi"
                    },
                    "probes": []
                }
            ],
            "initContainers": null,
            "scale": {
                "minReplicas": null,
                "maxReplicas": 5,
                "rules": [
                    {
                        "name": "order-accepted",
                        "azureQueue": {
                            "queueName": "order-accepted",
                            "queueLength": 10,
                            "auth": [
                                {
                                    "secretRef": "servicebus",
                                    "triggerParameter": "connection"
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "order-fulfilled",
                        "azureQueue": {
                            "queueName": "order-fulfilled",
                            "queueLength": 10,
                            "auth": [
                                {
                                    "secretRef": "servicebus",
                                    "triggerParameter": "connection"
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "order-rejected",
                        "azureQueue": {
                            "queueName": "order-rejected",
                            "queueLength": 10,
                            "auth": [
                                {
                                    "secretRef": "servicebus",
                                    "triggerParameter": "connection"
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "order-state",
                        "azureQueue": {
                            "queueName": "order-state",
                            "queueLength": 10,
                            "auth": [
                                {
                                    "secretRef": "servicebus",
                                    "triggerParameter": "connection"
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "process-order",
                        "azureQueue": {
                            "queueName": "process-order",
                            "queueLength": 5,
                            "auth": [
                                {
                                    "secretRef": "servicebus",
                                    "triggerParameter": "connection"
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "submit-order",
                        "azureQueue": {
                            "queueName": "submit-order",
                            "queueLength": 10,
                            "auth": [
                                {
                                    "secretRef": "servicebus",
                                    "triggerParameter": "connection"
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "validation",
                        "azureQueue": {
                            "queueName": "validation",
                            "queueLength": 10,
                            "auth": [
                                {
                                    "secretRef": "servicebus",
                                    "triggerParameter": "connection"
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    }
                ]
            },
            "volumes": [],
            "serviceBinds": null
        },
        "eventStreamEndpoint": "<redacted>"
    },
    "identity": {
        "type": "None"
    }
}
```

7+ minutes in, container is still alive.

[image: Console]

Can MassTransit's `AutoStart = true` for ASB cause this behaviour, or is there something off with my ContainerApps configuration?

Comment: with all the rules you've specified, can you confirm if does not scale to zero when there is no messages in any queue ?

Comment: also have you tried `minReplicas: 0` ?

Comment: also your bicep file does not seems to looks like this defined here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-apps/scale-app?pivots=azure-resource-manager#example-2

Comment: It might be `AutoStart = true` since that creates a separate queue that MassTransit listens on for responses. In my sample and videos, scale to zero clearly worked as expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Scaler rules are defined with azureQueue, they should be custom rules instead. Rewriting them with custom rules solves the issue:

```json
 "initContainers": null,
            "scale": {
                "minReplicas": 0,
                "maxReplicas": 5,
                "rules": [
                    {
                        "name": "order-accepted",
                        "custom": {
                            "type": "azure-servicebus",
                            "metadata": {
                                "messageCount": "1",
                                "namespace": "kkdevservicebus",
                                "queueName": "order-accepted"
                            },
                            "auth": [
                                {
                                    "secretRef": "servicebus",
                                    "triggerParameter": "connection"
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    },
...
```